# How to make our blogpost title to h1 from h2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help in formatting the heading tag of our blogpost titles from h2 to h1.

We are using justwrite theme in wordpress.

I have changed to h1s from h2s in the content.php templates under the post templates.

I have also purged the cache.

But the content titles are still displaying in h2 instead of h1.

By the way this is only affecting 2 newer blogposts:

1. https://www.roofventilationblog.com.au/subfloor-ventilation-the-ultimate-guide/1354/
2. https://www.roofventilationblog.com.au/5-warning-signs-to-upgrade-your-commercial-whirlybirds-to-solar-whirlybirds/1381/

Can anyone please enlighten and help me if I missed something in the process?

Please see the attached image.

I have changed all the template php to h1 but is not working on the 2 contents/blogposts mentioned above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3eFj.png)

And here is how our function.php looks like in child theme
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt10t.png)

I have browsed the previous questions here in stackoverflow but seems they aren't the answers I am looking for.

**July 10, 2023 Update:**
Here is how the parent theme looks like with the line of code
"ac_single_post_title_info_thumb" in the parent theme. How do I override it in the child theme so the post title will be h2 from h1?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6bRV.png)

**July 14, 2023 Update:**
After I copy pasted the "ac_single_post_title_info_thumb" function from the parent theme to the child theme functions.php, I can't access the wp-admin anymore. It is "loading" for so long and after a long time it displays this image below. I have purged the cache but it didn't solve the issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39BhC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply changes in post-templates folder.

template-page.php will only call for pages not for posts.

If still h2 tag is not replaced by h1 then try to override "ac_single_post_title_info_thumb" action in your child theme's functions.php file.
See screenshot for what code needs to be added to the child theme.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Komal Gondhali

Thanks for your reply.

All the h2s under post-templates have already been changed to h1.

I have also checked the functions.php in child theme to look for ac_single_post_title_info_thumb" but there is none.

This is how our functions.php look like in child theme

<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hubspot_blog_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function hubspot_blog_theme_enqueue_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

?>

Comment: That hook will be found in parent theme. You need to override in your child theme.

Comment: Hi @Komal Gondhali. You were right I found the "ac_single_post_title_info_thumb" in the parent theme. How do I override it in the child theme? Please see the attached image of the parent theme with that line of code in my original question/post. I have attached there the image of how the parent theme looks like. thank you.

Comment: See screenshot attached in my comment. You need to copy whole function with add_action hook and then replace h2 tag with h1.

Comment: Hi @Komal Gondhali, thank you so much for helping. The titles of the 2 latest blogs are now in H1. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have another question, after I have copy pasted the "ac_single_post_td" function. I can't seem to access the wp-admin anymore, it only has this infinite "loading". I tried purging the caches but it won't work. Have I done something wrong when I copy pasted the function to the functions.php of child theme? please see my original question for the screenshot